# How do I make the following scheme?

Tags: algorithms, schemata

How do I make this kind of scheme in TeX[image]

I found it in a book I'm using as source for my bachelor´s thesis and I thought it was a nice way of summarizing a method. But how do I implement it in TeX?

Or would you advise for a different way of displaying the algorithm, is this kind of display bad practice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In order for people to be able to help you, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you have tried so far and what exactly you are struggling with. This kind of question falls into the "do it for me" category of question and will most likely not be answered.

Comment: Aside from the absence of a compilable example, there are a few things that would make this a better question.  It's not at all clear exactly what you want information about.  The one answer so far addresses the symbols in two equations.  But you might also be wondering how to handle the enumerated steps in the "scheme".  The question heading doesn't identify anything specific that might attract attention, and the illustration doesn't really correspond to what is provided by any of the packages identified by the tags.  I'm sure you can improve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there are more variants, since I know nothing about your discipline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\tikzset{
  dot to dot/.style={
    every node/.style={inner sep=1.5pt, draw, circle}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \dotToDot { s } {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
    \tikzset{left dot/.style={fill}, right dot/.style={}}    
  }{
    \tikzset{left dot/.style={}, right dot/.style={fill}}
  }
  \mathrel{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        baseline={(0, -.5ex)},
        dot to dot
      ] 
      \node[left dot]  (left)              {};
      \node[right dot] (right) at (3em, 0) {};
      \draw (left) -- (right);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\Huge 

\begin{align*}
  p_\gamma(\xi) & \dotToDot  p_\gamma(q) \\
  p_\gamma(\xi) & \dotToDot* p_\gamma(q)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]